# Read part of every frame of a video file

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I'm doing some tracking on video files. First I separate frames using ffmpeg and the for each frame i apply a mask and then perform the tracking algorithm.

To make this process faster I'm thinking about reading only the parts I need. like reading the part that I apply the mask or better than that reading boxes around the previous positions of objects. So I'm looking for a way to decode and read a specific part of a specific frame from a video file. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: In a sense, video encoder performes object tracking to achieve best compression. Unfortunately, it does not consider a physical model that underlies the scene and may use completely impossible "virtual moves". This leads me to conclusion that trying to interpret "motion estimation vectors' of the compressed frames will unlikely prove fruitful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  Unless you know how every part of decoder (for the encoding that's used) works.

I would suggest you that you rather use some streaming algorithm - so that you don't have to store whole pictures from ffmpeg.

Comment: so i should write a decoder for my purpose. right? Any hint on how to start? like What should I use? (opengl,..)

Comment: I doubt that would accelerate the task.

Comment: Storing raw or compressed images on the disk is time consuming, despite the fact that little or no CPU is used.  You will still waste computer bandwidth.  I'm not suggesting that you write the decoder, just throwing an analogy for you to see how complex it is.